# Dynamic Programming algorithm

Tags: binary-tree, dynamic-programming, recurrence

A binary tree T is semi-balanced if for every node m in T:

R(m)/2 <= L(m) <= 2*R(m),

where L(m) is the number of nodes in the left-sub-tree of m and R(m) is the number of nodes in the right-sub-tree of m.

(a) Write a recurrence relation to count the number of semi-balanced binary trees with N
nodes.

(b) Provide a Dynamic Programming algorithm for computing the recurrence in (a).

How do i go about making the recurrence relation for this?

Does the following qualify?

```
if(node==NULL)
return;
if(given relation is true)
count++
else find for right tree;
     find for left tree;
```

I guess he is asking more of a recurrence relation like a function or something.?

Also how do i go about doing the problem using dynamic programming? I guess i dont need to store anything if i apply the above suggested code snippet.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let `C(n)` be number of semi-balanced trees with `n` nodes. If you know values for `C(1), C(2), ..., C(n)` than it is easy to calculate `C(n+1)` by taking root node and dividing remaining `n` nodes into left and right sub-trees by condition stated.

Number of nodes in sub-trees can be from `n/3` to `2*n/3`, since these values satisfy condition `R(n)/2 <= L(n) <= 2*R(n)`.

**Update:**

`C(n) = sum from n/3 to 2n/3 L(n)*R(n)`

Comment: @aksam What kind of example are you looking for? Recurrence code or example of calculation?

Comment: I am not clear with how recurrence fits together. let's say we know C(1) number of semi balance binary tree with 1 nodes how can we find C(2) number of semi balance binary tree with 1 nodes ?

Comment: @aksam I updated answer. C(n) is sum of all possible combinations of L and R subtrees.